# What does the Bible say about giving worship to a created being?

Tags: biblical-basis, angels, worship, adam, michael

Is there any biblical basis to support the view that God, through Michael the Archangel, commanded all the angels to worship Adam?  Why would God ask the angels to worship a created human?  Doesn’t the Bible say to worship God alone?

This question arises as a result of a recent question: What is an overview of explanations for why fallen angels are motivated to attack Christians?  [According to Protestantism, why are fallen angels motivated to attack Christians?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/73854/why-are-the-fallen-angels-so-bent-into-destroying-believers-is-it-because-of-je)

One answer quotes from a source which says: “Michael went out and called all the angels saying: 'Worship the image of God as the Lord God hath commanded.' And Michael himself worshipped first; then he called me and said: 'Worship the image of God the Lord.' And I answered, 'I have no (need) to worship Adam.' And since Michael kept urging me to worship, I said to him, 'Why dost thou urge me? I will not worship an inferior and younger being (than I). I am his senior in the Creation, before he was made was I already made. It is his duty to worship me.'”  (1913 English translation of the Latin version of the Life of Adam and Eve chapters 12-16, section xiv)

Another source here: http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/759-adam-book-of

When challenged by the Jewish scribes as to which was the most important commandment, Jesus answered, “The most important is, ‘Hear, O Israel: The Lord our God, the Lord is one. And you shall love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your mind and with all your strength.’” (Mark 12:28-30) Jesus’ answer was based on the ‘Shema’ in Deuteronomy 6:4.

Yet God the creator commanded the created angels to worship a created human, Adam?  I realise there are various apocryphal sources that support this view but what does the Bible say about giving worship to a created being?

For example, if it is unbiblical to worship a created being (whether an angel or a human), then why does Hebrews 1:6 quote from Psalm 97:7 and say that all God's angels are to worship Christ Jesus, the Son of God?  Surely this must prove that Christ Jesus, the Son of God, was never a created angel?

Comment: Worship is not restricted to religious adoration; it generally means to bow down (for instance to a ruler, not necessarily a divinity). Since man is the image of God (Genesis 1:27), the Supreme Ruler, and since it was customarily for ancient kings to have images of themselves paraded through the cities and villages over which they ruled, and have their subjects bow to these as they would to their real-life flesh and blood equivalent, it is only reasonable that man should be shown the same respect, having the rest of creation worship him as its rightful ruler (Genesis 1:28).

Comment: Exodus 20:2-5: “You shall have no other gods before me.  You shall not make for yourself an idol...  You shall not bow down to them or worship them; for I, the LORD your God, am a jealous God...”

Comment: In the referenced text, were the angels instructed to worship Adam as god ?

Comment: Is the "referenced text" the article in the Jewish Encyclopedia about the Book of Adam?

Comment: I was referring to the apocryphal book itself, though encyclopedic articles about it can also be helpful.

Comment: Thank you, Lucian. Regardless of what any apocryphal book says about God telling the angels to worship Adam, my question is asking what does the Bible tell us about the worship of created beings. If you have any biblical insights into the meaning of "worship" and how this relates to the 'Shema' (to worship God alone) please post an answer. As for the difference between the Lord God Almighty, who is the Creator, and to 'gods' please feel free to express your views.

Comment: My main point was that your question is linguistic rather than theological. You act as if the book in question and/or the Bible were originally written in modern English, where the word *worship* nowadays usually means worship of the divine, specifically. To my knowledge, the Anglican marriage service still has the two spouses exchanging *with my body I thee worship* as part of their marital vows.

Comment: Fear not, Lucian, I am aware that the Old Testament was written in Hebrew and the New Testament in koine Greek and Aramaic. There is an element of seeking to understand the meaning of the Hebrew word translated into English as "worship" but the main thrust of my question is theological. To whom do we give our worship, to the creator or to the created? Would any of God's angels worship a created being? Should any human worship a created being? What does the Bible say about giving worship to a created being? And no, I'm not talking about worshipping your spouse with your body.

Comment: *the Hebrew **word** translated into English as "worship"* - My point was that there is not just one *word* (singular), but rather *words* (plural), which are translated into English as such, and, depending upon choice of words and context, the answer to this question might vary. In the mean time, see Hebrews 1:6.

Comment: Related https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/62987/23657

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source you are quoting is "[The Life of Adam and Eve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_of_Adam_and_Eve)", which is a [Jewish Apocryphal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_apocrypha) writing. This means that it is not accepted as authoritative by either Christians or Jews. There is widespread agreement that it was composed in the first century after Christ, and thus not in any way contemporary with Biblical creation accounts.

In actual biblical writings, and even in non-biblical widely-accepted writings, there is no indication that God commanded angels to worship Adam. Doing so would go against the will of God expressed in many places in the Bible that God himself is the only being worthy of worship. You quote some of the key passages in the question, but there are plenty of others, such as Luke 4:8.

The Christian response to this dilemma is simple - the account in The Life of Adam and Eve is incorrect. No Christian group that I am aware of treats it as anything other than a man-made fictional story.

Comment: Also, see revelation 22:8-9 for a related verse in which John attempts to worship an angel, and the angel instructs him.

Comment: *God himself is the only being worthy of worship* - God is the only *divinity* worthy of worship; unless one is willing to argue that righteous biblical Jews repeatedly broke the Mosaic Law whenever they bowed down before a king (1 Kings 1:23) or prophet (2 Kings 2:15).

Comment: @Lucian There is a difference between "bowing down" and 'worshipping".

Comment: Exodus 20:2-5: “You shall have no other gods before me.  You shall not make for yourself an idol...  You shall not bow down to them or worship them; for I, the LORD your God, am a jealous God...”

Comment: @DJClayworth: Precisely. The same word can have more than one meaning.

Comment: "There is a difference between "bowing down" and 'worshipping"" Not in ye olde English or in ancient Hebrew.  To prostrate oneself in veneration of a king, master, any royalty, a patriarch, etc. would be called "worship," but it was known to be distinct from divine adoration—the sense to which we've artificially restricted the sense of "worship" in English since its original usages. E.g. in 16th century English it was perfectly normal to trans. Ruth 2:10 "She fell on her face and *worshipping* upon the ground, said to him: Whence cometh this to me, that I should find grace before thy eyes..?"

Comment: It referred to the gesture itself, not the kind of attitude or intention behind it, or the view the person had of the recipient of said gesture (i.e. as a god, or someone worthy of their profound outward display of honor).

Comment: Case in point: 1 Chronicles 29:20: "And David commanded all the assembly: Bless ye the Lord our God. And all the assembly blessed the Lord the God of their fathers: and they bowed themselves and worshipped God, and then the king." Clearly worship could apply to men and God, except to 'worship' God was an outward display of complete submission to the deity, whereas to 'worship' the king referred to the profound honor due to those in authority.